# Bootstrap.js missing from dist folder after using Grunt command

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm scaffolding a project with Yeoman and I encountered a problem recently. When I use grunt command on a command line to make distribution version of a project it modifies my index.html and deletes bootstrap.min.js script. Everything else stays the same, it just from some reason deletes that one line of code.

Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Which generator did you use? Which options did you select?

Comment: I used generator webapp and selected add bootstrap only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the webapp generator, all bootstrap.js files get concatenated into the plugins.js file.

If you look in your index.html file (in the app folder) you should see the block of code I've added here

note the **build:js scripts/plugins.js** - that's what tells grunt to concatenate the files into the plugins.js file

You can rename plugins.js to bootstrap.min.js in that line if you'd like

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/headroom/headroom.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>

    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>

    <!-- endbuild -->
```